# Able to run 2 yields at same time using flask but to check the performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, yield-return

I have created the code to run two yields in while true conditions using flask but Recently I was able to create some change Its working fine but It is displaying continuous response like mentioned below snapshot

[image]

My original code is as mentioned below

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify
import cv2
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

app = Flask(__name__)

class VideoCamera:
    def __init__(self):
        # Using OpenCV to capture from device 0. If you have trouble capturing
        # from a webcam, comment the line below out and use a video file
        # instead.
        #self.video = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:root%40123@10.1.1.1:554/Streaming/Channels/101")
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#        # If you decide to use video.mp4, you must have this file in the folder
        # as the main.py.
        # self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        # We are using Motion JPEG, but OpenCV defaults to capture raw images,
        # so we must encode it into JPEG in order to correctly display the
        # video stream.
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return ret, jpeg.tobytes()

camera = VideoCamera()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


def gen():
    while True:
        _,frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

def gen1():
    while True:
        print(camera.get_frame()[0])
        yield str(camera.get_frame()[0])

@app.route('/ap')
def p2():
    #ab_next = next(gen1())
    return Response(gen1())


@app.route('/video_fed')
def video_fed():
        return Response(gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

# @app.route('/video_fed')
# def video_fed(camera1):
#     ret,_ = camera1.get_frame()
#     return jsonify(ret)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #from yourapplication import app
    #from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
    # http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5000), app)
    # http_server.serve_forever()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

Suggestions if anything I have to change or is this thing will better performance-wise or should I change something else?

Comment: You used `while True:` rather extensively. In practice that is something you should avoid in web application.

Comment: I do not know much about live video streaming, which seem to be what you are trying to do. I do know how Flask apps work, and it seems like you are assuming that the script will be reloaded whenever serving a new request (like is the case with PHP). You therefore seem to rely on the line `data = frame1()` line being run for every request, which I assume is your way of fetching a new frame. However this line would only run once per worker process initialization, so you will not be getting new frames. This may have ill effects on your code. I do not see the connections to the loops.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the video part, and just run the code with two functions that yield something (e.g. integers) to see if the issue is in any way related to the use of yield?

Comment: I did some changes but I am not sure whether its working fine or not

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error you're facing is unrelated to the use of two `yield`, but rather to CV2's inability to access the camera - or something similar.

At least on Mac, you have to allow the application to access the camera. Without it, you'll get the following error:

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:877: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !image.empty() in function 'imencode'`

Comment: @varuljain works like a charm. The "video_fed" endpoint shows the video stream coming from the camera. The 'ap' endpoint returns what seems to be an endless sequence of 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with `debug=False`. You are creating a while loop in the main loop of your application and when debbuger is enabled it enables the reloader which can mess up everything, especially the frame collector loop. If you wanna use the debbuger just set `use_reloader=False`.